# Moderator Election - Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Photography last had an election [back in 2017](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/5). Right now we have an opportunity to run an election for the site, and after consulting with the mods, it sounds like it is a good time for 1 or 2 new slots to open up.

To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 5):

I would consider standing if it looks like we don't have enough suitable candidates.

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination

Answer (score 3):

Count me in (will try again :) )

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination

Answer (score 3):

I've thought about this for a few days. I would consider nominating myself, but before I would do so, I'd like the chance to chat briefly with one or more of the existing mods here.

Comment: Away for the weekend, but happy to chat next week

Comment: @MikeW thanks, no hurry. Enjoy your weekend!

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination