# 2020 Community Moderator Election - Failed Election

Tags: discussion, election

As [previously announced](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/why-was-the-2020-election-nomination-period-extended) the current election wasn't able to gather the required number of candidates to be competitive. We must consider this a failed election and have halted it.

The next steps are for the Community to consider here what may have gone wrong, if we can have more interest on a new one, and if so, when can we host a new one.

We usually wait a month between elections and trying again, however, being that we have many elections to run across the network, it may be possible to wait a little bit longer, but not a ton, Photography needs an election sooner rather than later.

Thank you!

Comment: Would it count as competitive if I were to run while endorsing the others? :)

Comment: @gerrit Well, yes. But we also don't recommend people running just to inflate the count.

Answer (score 16):

I hesitated to recommend this prior to the deadline, but I see no risk doing so now: couldn't the number of open mod slots have been reduced to 1, to at least have an election? As it stands, our current moderators won't get any relief at all. At least with an election for 1 slot, they can bring a new mod up to speed and possibly start taking the load off of them.

Comment: We can do this in a second election, sure! And that's probably what we'll do next. Once the nomination period starts, though, I don't think the system is able to adjust the number of seats, plus, it would be a tiny bit confusing to have that change happen - that said, as long as it doesn't happen during voting, it's probably not a big deal.

Comment: @Catija Is there going to be a 2nd election? As I understand it, the network had several elections to take care of around the same time as Photo-SE's (almost) happened, so I can understand some delay. What's the scuttlebutt re: Photo-SE?

Comment: Yep, we're looking into it now. :) I think we'll be having one scheduled to start again in the next week or so.

Comment: @scottbb the second attempt is now live.

Comment: @CesarM **2 positions available again?!?** We failed the last election because there were only 2 nominations w/ 2 positions available. Do you (i.e, SE org) have new or additional information to lead you to believe you'll have more nominations than last time? I barely nominated myself last time before the deadline. Part of my hesitation was wondering if there's enough of a community to even be worth the effort. After failing the election, and seeing how long it took for SE to start up a 2nd election, I'm wondering if there's enough support from SE, let alone PSE community support.

Answer (score 4):

Any attempt to garner nominations might be more successful if the page upon which nominations can be made was not <s>totally</s> almost impossible to find.

Answer (score 2):

I did not see the previous election happen. I might have been busy and away, and not in Photography anyway. This time (21th september), I saw the message in the inbox while on SO.

Maybe the staff could see the response to such an event or if people are clicking to the inbox message and then read things about it; hence the staff could see if the impact of communicating in a way or another, and adapt. Or do polls about community interests in such event (nomination, election).

Comment: Hi Soleil. There was a [community interest check in mid May](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7034/11924), followed by an [election Q&A collection](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7038/11924) and [election](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7043/11924), both in June.

Comment: @scottbb As I thought, with respectively 166, 54, 61 views for the posts you mentionned, the visilibity (and maybe interest) is low.

Comment: Yeah, I’m concerned about the low visibility and interest as well.