# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the [official election page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election) for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Are we attempting to elect one or two moderators this time around?

Comment: @MichaelC yeah, it’s 2 again. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

We're trying again from the [old failed moderator election](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7050/2020-community-moderator-election-failed-election).

To make it so that candidates do not need to answer a new questionnaire, we'll be using the same questionnaire as last time - people can [answer it here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/2020-moderator-election-qa-v2-questionnaire) and [nominate themselves here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/7).

Answer (score 2):

The nomination period for this election has been extended because we need more candidates!

Please visit the [election page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/7) and consider nominating.